# C Typecasts in #define directives

Tags: c, casting, c-preprocessor

I've seen many #defines for literals using a type cast.
As example `#define THE_ANSWER ((uint8_t) 42)`.

Until now, I can hardly imagine a situation where this really matters.

Can someone give me an example where a #define directive without a type cast leads to an "unexpected" behaviour.
Maybe there is a good example for desktop environment and one for embedded or microcontroller environment.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Sometimes you want to avoid signedness issues and stick to unsigned values (mostly for bitwise operations).

Comment: Isn't it more common to see something like: `42u` rather than `(uint8_t)42`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits `42u` is an `unsigned int`, not a `uint8_t`.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that for coding standards for high integrity software such as MISRA all preprocessor definitions need to be surround by brackets and have a typecast. There's too many subtle bugs that can occur especially as code gets more complex

Comment: try outputting `sizeof(THE_ANSWER)`

Comment: @FiddlingBits I don't know that it's all that common that people are even aware of the existence of explicitly unsigned integer literals.

Comment: @FiddlingBits `42u` is an unsigned integer, typically 4 bytes these days but could be 2, 8, or something else.  `(uint8_t)42` will be a different type and only be 1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

One example is multiplication. Say you have the following:

```
#define KILO 1024
```

what happens if you later on do the following?

```
unsigned long long val = KILO * KILO * KILO * KILO * KILO * ...
```

you might think that the multiplication would get evaluated with the type `unsigned long long`, but in reality all those multiplications happen on `int`. So if your directive doesn't have a typecast, or better yet it isn't `1024L` you might end up with unexpected behavior because of an `int` overflow, even though your variable's type can actually hold the result.